# Redirecting subdirectory to subdomain in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I want to redirect a subdirectory to a subdomain using `.htaccess`. My current code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?sub.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory [L]
</IfModule>
```

This code redirects to `sub.example.com/subdirectory`. How do I remove `/subdirectory` from the new URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this rule on top, before all other rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ http://www.sub.example.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

**Complete .htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !subdirectory subdirectory%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Now I can access sub.example.com, but two problems arise: the Wordpress is messed up, here is a screenshot of it: http://s8.postimg.org/5rupjqwdv/image.png - there is no template structure, styles, etc. Second problem is that now example.com/subdirectory leads to www.sub.example.com - and www is a missing URL. Maybe if we redirect www to non-www it will solve this problem?

Comment: For style, JS etc solution is simple, just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: Also may I know is `www.sub.example.com` also managed by Wordpress OR not?

Comment: Yes, sub.example.com is on Wordpress. I didn`t get your previous suggestion - do I have to manually edit the CSS of the website?

Comment: so `www.sub.example.com` is wordpress and `www.example.com` is also wordpress?

Comment: Yes. But sub.example.com is actually a subdomain - it uses the Wordpress (the directory) of example.com/subdirectory. And the idea is example.com/subdirectory to point to sub.example.com

Comment: In that case there will be a `.htaccess` inside subdirectory also. Post it in your question.

Comment: There is no .htaccess actually in the subdirectory? Only in the root one

Comment: Oh ok and what is DOCUMENT_ROOT of `www.sub.example.com`? Is it same as `www.example.com`?

Comment: The root is example.com.                                                                 Inside the root (which is the WP installation), there is a folder called subdirectory - there is the example.com/subdirectory or sub.example.com

Comment: Yes that I know but I wanted to know DOCUMENT_ROOT value of `www.sub.example.com` from your `VirtualHost` config?

Comment: I am sorry, but where can I check this? I am not sure what this means. :(

Comment: That is defined in `VirtualHost section` in `Apache config`.

Comment: I am not sure that I can check this, because I have only access to FTP - no access to CPanel. This is why I wanted to work only with the htaccess.

Comment: Ok coming back to your problems. What exactly are the problems with above suggested rule?

Comment: Your redirect makes example.com/subdirectory redirect to WWW.sub.example.com - which is a non-existing site (it has to be without www). Can we make a rule that states that subdomains with www should always redirect to such with non-www? This will solve the problem, in my opinion

Comment: Now it redirects directly to non-www, but if somebody types www.sub.experiment.com - it shows an error?

Comment: If `www.sub.experiment.com` doesn't even exist why and how would anyone type it?

Comment: I mean that people tend to type www.site.com? Do you see my point?

Comment: Yes but that needs to be fixed by your hosting company's DNS record. If `www.sub.experiment.com` doesn't exist then request won't even come to your Apache web server.

Comment: Thanks A LOT, Anubhava! You are super! :))